# Stationary points of : $y' = y^3 + y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stationary-point

I have a question regarding stationary points and their behavior.

**Exercise :**

> Discuss the behavior of the stationary points of the differential equation :
>   $$y' = y^3 + y$$

**Attempt :**

We can easily see that the stationary points are :

$$y^3 + y = 0 \Leftrightarrow y(y^2 + 1) =  \Leftrightarrow y =  \begin{cases}0\\
\pm1 \end{cases}$$

So, our stationary points are at : $a=0, b=i, c = -i$ .

To find their behavior :

First of all, we have that if $y<0$ then $y'<0 \forall y\in(-\infty,0)$, which (by theory) means :

$$\lim_{t\to -\infty}y(t) = 0, \lim_{t\to\infty}y(t) = -\infty$$

Is this correct, first of all ?

Secondly, I wanted to ask, how do I handle the $imaginary$ stationary points ? How will I study their behavior since I cannot proceed (or I can't see how to proceed) with analysing the sign of $y$ ?

Comment: Unless you are specifically taking a course about ODEs with a complex time variable, you can safely just ignore the roots $\pm i$.

Comment: I'm taking a Dynamical Systems course. I think it would need us to handle the complex roots. How would I proceed in this case ? Also, my limits for $y<0$ are correct?

Comment: There is a typo in your stationary points.

Comment: What is the meaning of the statements $$y<0$$ and $$y'<0$$ if $y$ is allowed to take complex, non real, values? That is, which order relation are you considering in the complex plane? :-) IOW, I join the chorus of people who tried to explain that the only relevant fixed point here is $$y=0$$ and that, no, you are most probably not expected to consider the fixed points $$\pm i$$

Comment: @Did This is exactly why I asked, because the sign analyzing process wouldn't hold for the complex equilibria.

Comment: OK, but why did you write $y<0$ and $y'<0$ if you had in mind that $y$ is complex valued?

Comment: @Did Because the exercise is asking you to work through the sign analyzing process and there may was a way to work around complex numbers involving the length of a complex number. I also do not understand your attitude. It's clear that I was asking for something I wouldn't know how to grasp.

Comment: ((A comment explaining why the OP is misled, mathematically speaking, and why it is unfortunate that they do not listen, got deleted. One can regret it, but, frankly, my plan is to let things as they are...))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linearize the system at the equilibrium points to obtain:

$$\Delta y' = [3y_{\text{eq}}^2+1]\Delta y$$

We obtain for $y_{\text{eq}}=0$

$$\Delta y' = [3\cdot0^2+1]\Delta y=\Delta y$$

which is unstable.

For $y_{\text{eq}}=\pm i$ we obtain
$$\Delta y' = [3(i)^2+1]\Delta y= -2\Delta y.$$

This would imply that the complex equilibria are stable (whatever the meaning of this might be). Like @Hans Lundmark suggested normally you would ignore these equilibria.